# Extracting a data from one workbook and paste it in another

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file in drive "D".I would like to copy the data from workbook
"raw" from sheet1 to the another workbook "SC" in sheet "BW".

I am using the below code, to extract the data from one workbook and pasting it to another.

```
Sub extract()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim Val As Variant
Dim filename As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
CopyCol = Split("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X", ",")
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LCell = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
LCC = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LCR = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Set y = ThisWorkbook ' set ThisWorkbook object (where this code lies)
Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Student\Jenny\Raw.xlsx")
For Count = 0 To UBound(CopyCol)
Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1:" & CopyCol(Count) & LCR)
If Count = 0 Then
Set CopyRange = temp
Else
Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
End If
Next
CopyRange.Copy
y.Sheets("BW").Range("A5").PasteSpecial
x.Close
End Sub
```

This code is workin, but the problem is , in my sheet "sheet1" I have my data starting from A4, and would like to copy the data in destination sheet "BW" from A5.
The current code, paste the copied data from A7. How can I modify such a way that it pastes the copied data from A5.

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: In `Set temp` try `4` instead of `1` as `Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1:" & CopyCol(Count) & LCR)`

Comment: It worked :) Can you also tell me, How I can select an particular sheet from source sheet. ? because In one workbook I have several sheets, and I need data from "Result" sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Set temp` try `4` instead of `1` as

```
Set temp = Range(CopyCol(Count) & "1:" & CopyCol(Count) & LCR)
```

> How I can select an particular sheet (*Sheet Result*) from source sheet. ?

Use

```
With x.Sheets("Result")
.
.
.
End With
```

or

`x.Sheets("Result").` or whatever you are trying.

You have many unused and undeclared variables. Your updated code may look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub extract()
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
    Dim temp As Range, CopyRange As Range
    Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, LCR As Long, Count As Long
    Dim copycol
    copycol = Split("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X", ",")
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set y = ThisWorkbook ' set ThisWorkbook object (where this code lies)
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("D:\Student\Jenny\Raw.xlsx")

    With x.Sheets("Result")
    LCR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Count = 0 To UBound(copycol)
            Set temp = .Range(copycol(Count) & "4:" & copycol(Count) & LCR)
            If Count = 0 Then
                Set CopyRange = temp
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, temp)
            End If
        Next
        CopyRange.Copy
        y.Sheets("BW").Range("A5").PasteSpecial
    End With
    x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jenny - See my code. I've updated it by removing unused and undeclared variable.